# ForIn Loop Works but return doesn't make sense

Tags: javascript, api, ecmascript-6, request, for-in-loop

I just want to console.log two properties of a json return from an api call. I've never used the request library. When I try to loop through body it just returns strings and I can see the line carriages. With axios I made the call and looped through it with no problem...

I tried using a for, forin, and object entries. I don't understand the output.

```
const request = require("request");

async function GetPosts() {
    await request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", function (error, response, body) {
        for (const key in body) {
            if (body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                const element = body[key];
                console.log(element);
            }
        }
    });
}
GetPosts();
```

I just want to print title and body properties from the json result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `JSON.parse()` to parse the response body into an object.

Then when you loop over the elements of the array, you should just print the properties you want, not the whole object.

```
const request = require("request");

async function GetPosts() {
    await request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", function (error, response, body) {
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        body.forEach(item => {
            console.log(item.title, item.body);
        });
    });
}
GetPosts();
```

Comment: I didn't realize I had to parse it. I thought the library would take care of it for me. I'm used to using axios. By the way, when I run the code, it gives two undefined next to each other. When I run it like this, it actually logs it. If it's supposed to work you suggest in the snippet above, am I doing something wrong? I would very much like to go for the simpler syntax

Comment: What I have here is working, I just want to know why it's returning undefined if I could use the shorter syntax

Comment: After it parsed it, it actually turned it in to an array of objects to where I could use the for in loop. It all makes sense now.

Comment: I didn't realize it was an array of objects, I've updated the answer.